# What is the quickest way to 'find' a file in an often used directory in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I access a lot of files from a certain directory which is not ~ but say: 
D:\Mijn documenten\My Dropbox.

What is the quickest way to 'find' a file in that directory within a new Emacs session? Using bookmarks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically switch to another buffer editing a file in that common directory so that when I `C-x C-f` to find a new file, the path is already showing the directory I want.

This works for new sessions because I have `desktop-save-mode` enabled to [save my session](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html#Saving-Emacs-Sessions) when I exit emacs (and the only time I exit emacs is if I'm updating emacs or have to reboot my machine).

Comment: Ain't that many keys, especially if you didn't *just* used one ? Switching is `C-x b <find one> RET`, right ?

Answer (score 3):

`ido` is really nice for this exact reason.  These are the sites where I first read about it:

- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings
- http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2009/02/switching-buffers.html#sec-1.2

Answer (score 1):

You can open any directory you choose in *dired*.  (*C-xd* and directory name.)  You can search for the filename in the *dired* buffer.

If you simply want to change the current directory to be */something/else* instead of *~*, you can do *M-x cd* and change it to the directory you want.  The next time you do *C-x C-f* to open a file, you will be in the different directory.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at [Speedbar](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar).

> Speedbar is another frame which
>   displays information about the current
>   buffer, allowing you to better
>   navigate your sources.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bind “going to that dir” to a single key, and <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> from there.

```
(defun my-favorite-directory ()
    "Open where I often go."
    (interactive)
    (find-file "/path/to/there"))
(global-set-key [f5] 'my-favorite-directory) ; Let it be a global bookmark.
```

Or, as you suggest, I'm sure you could use [bookmarks](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/BookMarks).

Answer (score 0):

Two packages that are good at this aside from the ones already mentioned:

- [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile)

  - any version-controlled folder is a "project"
  - you can quickly jump to any project and then any file inside a project
  - add a `.projectile` file to identify other folders as "projects"
  - integrates with ido, helm, ivy (recommended)
- [emacs-fasd](https://github.com/steckerhalter/emacs-fasd)

  - thin layer on top of [the command-line utility](https://github.com/clvv/fasd)
  - jump to commonly used files and directories
  - integrates with ido, helm, ivy (recommended)

Of course, for *very* frequently accessed files, like my dotfiles, I do the following:

```
(defmacro radian-register-dotfile (filename &optional keybinding)
  "Tell Radian about a dotfile.

This is best demonstrated by example. If NAME is
\".emacs.d/init.el\" then `radian-register-dotfile' will create
the interactive function `radian-find-init-el'. Calling that
function will invoke `find-file' on ~/.emacs.d/init.el.

If additionally KEYBINDING is \"e i\" then
`radian-register-dotfile' will use `global-set-key' to bind
`radian-find-init-el' to (kbd \"M-RET e i\")."
  (let* ((bare-filename (replace-regexp-in-string ".*/" "" filename))
         (defun-name (make-symbol
                      (concat
                       "radian-find-"
                       (replace-regexp-in-string "[^a-z0-9]" "-" bare-filename))))
         (full-filename (concat "~/" filename))
         (docstring (format "Open %s in the current buffer."
                            full-filename))
         (defun-form `(defun ,defun-name ()
                        ,docstring
                        (interactive)
                        (find-file ,full-filename))))
    (if keybinding
        (let* ((full-keybinding (concat "M-RET " keybinding))
               (set-key-form `(global-set-key (kbd ,full-keybinding)
                                              #',defun-name)))
          `(progn
             ,defun-form
             ,set-key-form))
      defun-form)))

;; Emacs
(radian-register-dotfile ".emacs.d/init.el" "e i")
(radian-register-dotfile ".emacs.d/init.before.local.el" "e b")
(radian-register-dotfile ".emacs.d/init.local.el" "e l")

;; Git
(radian-register-dotfile ".gitconfig" "g c")
(radian-register-dotfile ".gitexclude" "g e")
(radian-register-dotfile ".gitconfig.local" "g l")

;; Et cetera
```

My `init.el` is [here](https://github.com/raxod502/radian/blob/master/init.el).

I hear that Emacs also has [file registers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Registers.html), which are used for the same purpose as my custom macro above.

Answer (score 0):

1. If this is about having a preferred directory be the default (`default-directory`) when you start an Emacs session, then just *start Emacs in that directory*.  For example, in MS Windows you would put that directory in the `Start in` field of a shortcut that you use to start Emacs.

   No need to use `desktop-save-mode`, if you always want to have that directory be the current one at Emacs startup.

   And you can show Dired for that directory when you start Emacs: just pass the directory as the file to edit on the command line.
2. If you want a persistent, quick way to get to a particular directory, making it the default, and showing Dired for it, then just create a Dired bookmark.  That is, create a bookmark when you are in a Dired buffer.  You will want library [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) for bookmarking Dired buffers.